# How to query REST API

Tags: api, rest, adobe

I am using this code below to deal with the REST API query for Adobe Analytics. I always get the message "something went wrong" which means that the first IF is not active.

```
include_once('/path/SimpleRestClient.php');

$username = 'XXXXX';
$secret = 'XXXXX';
$nonce = md5(uniqid(php_uname('n'), true));
$nonce_ts = date('c');

$digest = base64_encode(sha1($nonce.$nonce_ts.$secret));

$server = "https://api.omniture.com";       
$path = "/admin/1.4/rest/";

$rc=new SimpleRestClient();
$rc->setOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-WSSE: UsernameToken Username=\"$username\", PasswordDigest=\"$digest\", Nonce=\"$nonce\", Created=\"$nonce_ts\""));

$query="?method=Company.GetTokenUsage";

$rc->getWebRequest($server.$path.$query);

if ($rc->getStatusCode()==200) 
{
    $response=$rc->getWebResponse();
    var_dump($response);
} 
else 
{
    echo "something went wrong\n";
    var_dump($rc->getInfo());
}
```

The `$rc->getStatusCode();` does not exit. I get '404' when I use this line :

```
print_r ($rc->getStatusCode());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling, I found https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/blog/how-to-start-with-the-omniture-rest-api-in-php.  It uses API version of `1.3` instead of `1.4`.  By updating the

```
$path = "/admin/1.4/rest/";
```

to

```
$path = "/admin/1.3/rest/";
```

I was able to stop getting 404 errors in the browser.